# File not reading in correctly

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a program that reads in a file. All my classes compile fine, but there seems to be an error when I read in the file. Eclipse shows an empty string is being read in (""), which is not what I want.

I have the code for my main below with a while loop. I placed the loop just to see how it would run when debugging, and it runs an infinite loop since it is always reading in "", and never reaches end of file. I have put the file in the working directory and every other folder just to be sure, but it is always doing this even though the file is full of strings and integers. Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

```
#include "Translator.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream readFile;
    readFile.open("sample.html");

    while (!readFile.eof()) // for debugging purposes only
    {
    string x;

    readFile >> x; // x is "" everytime through the loop
    readFile >> x; // x is also ""
    }
    Translator t(readFile);

    readFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try: `string x; while(readFile >> x);`

Comment: Title says C, code is C++, tag is C++. Now what.

Comment: @H2CO3 Java or Smalltalk. You choose =P

Comment: Is the file really open? I mean, check for bad()

Comment: @AndréPuel I tried and if(readFile.bad()) and it skips right over it

Comment: @WhozCraig I tried that, but it is still doing the same thing.

Comment: Is the sample file really an html file?

Comment: I have tried putting it in as an html and text file, but with same results.

Comment: I am genuinely curious what possible file you have (by the looks of it an html file at that) that that causes `string x; while(readFile >> x);` to loop forever. If the file could not be opened, that loop terminates. If the file was a gigabyte of null-chars, that loop still, eventually, terminates. Any chance you can post that thing somewhere?? Also, just for fun, open the file in a **binary** editor or hex-dumper and see if there is a BOM in the lead bytes. Just curious.

Comment: @WhozCraig I changed the file a text file (does same things) and here is the link for it: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/20608771/sample.txt

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing wrong or wickedly unusual with that file content. it reads just fine. [see it live](http://ideone.com/rX7PKf). Note IDEOne pushes it through stdin, but I ran it at home off the fs (prog.exe input.txt) and identical output. Something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your file did not actually open, and the `eof` bit was therefore not set.  You never test whether the file was opened successfully.  It could be that your working directory is not what you think it is, or the file is locked by another process (perhaps open in a text editor).

Officially, you can test `readFile.fail()` after you try opening.

I've found that checking `readFile.good()` is fine too - in fact you can use that as your loop condition.

I prefer the positive message of 'good' in my code, rather than the potentially upsetting 'fail'.

You should also test your stream as WhozCraig suggested in comments, when you are reading data.  You cannot assume that the operation was successful.  If it fails for reasons other than EOF, you need to know.

For these reasons, don't use `readFile.eof()` as your loop condition.

Comment: @brent-mitchel I mixed bad with fail, you should have tested fail() instead of bad()

Comment: Thanks, with the good() I was able to figure out what directory it should have been in and I guess it is working now even though I didn't change my code... I restarted Eclipse too, so I don't know what it was doing, but thanks.